# Calling from in App dialer, android goes into ringing state but call is not getting placed to given number

Tags: android, phone-call, android-dialer, android-connectionservice

I am trying to make an In App Dialer via which I can make calls from inside my app and the calls gets placed to another number (who does not need to have our app, for another person it will just be a normal call).
The problem which is happening is that I have implemented the ConnectionService, Connection classes and used placeCall function to do this but it is still not placing the call, my android is telling that it is in off_hook state but in actual the call is not getting connected. I am using react native **Native Modules** to invoke the function inside the Native to make them work properly.

Most of the code which I have used is from https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep repo but still the call is not getting placed.

I have implemented my Connectionservice, Connection class, onCreateOugoingConnection function and all and still the call is not happening, I have done the steps as per this https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged, but still the call is not getting placed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.